# problems with sending emails from localhost

Tags: macos, email, localhost

I am on a mac, using mountain lion. I'm running php on a localhost environment and am writing a script that needs to send emails. Obviously I need to test if this script is working at various occasions. To do this I have tried to set up my machine to send emails to my gmail account, without success.

I know very little of the command line so have had to follow tutorials blindly. [this one seemed helpful](http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/), but has not been the only one I have followed. While following it i got an error message when I tried to open

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

after entering my password I got the message:

While opening file "/etc/postfix/main.cf"
             dated: Fri Jul 26 15:25:39 2013
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.
    If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
    different instances of the same file when making changes.
    Quit, or continue with caution.

(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/postfix/main.cf"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/postfix/.main.cf.swp"
    to avoid this message.

I tried to use

vim -r /etc/postfix/main.cf

and ive been presented with a list of files of the same name ending with different extensions, I selected a file (I assume they are store as backups and are all essentially the same) and edited it accordingly.

On completing the tut, I tried to send myself an email, but without success.

Is the error I came across the problem or is there likly to be an issue with spam filtering?

what are my options to send mail from my localhost

===EDIT===

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.zenddeveloper.com/how-to-send-smtp-mails-with-postfix-mac-os-x-10-8/) and I check if the email send with mailq, the responce i get is the Queue Id number, Size, Arrival time and Sender/recipient but no error message. When I have previously tried I got a timed out message. I sill have message in my Gmail account, is this due to not having an SMTP set as mentioned in the below comment?

I really need to send mail from my local host

Comment: You need to use an actual SMTP server.  Running your own SMTP server is a very involved task and is not recommended.

Comment: Are there no other options?